# Proving formula with binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I would like to prove the following conjecture for $n$ positive integer:

$$\sum_{k=\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \rfloor}^{n}{k{k-1 \choose \lfloor \frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor - 1}} = \Big\lceil \frac{n}{2} \Big\rceil{n+1 \choose \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}$$

and in particular, if $n=2m$:

$$\sum_{k=m}^{2m}{k{k-1 \choose m-1}} = m{2m+1 \choose m}$$

The LHS counts the sum of the maximum elements of each subset of $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ with size $\lfloor (n+1)/2 \rfloor$. For example for $n=3$ there are three subsets $\{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{2,3\}$ and the sum of maximum values is $2+3+3=8$.

I have searched with [Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3Dn%7D%5E%7B2n%7D%7Bk%7Bk-1%20%5Cchoose%20n%7D%7D%24&p=2) but I didn't find the above equality.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As regards the case $n=2m$,
$$\sum_{k=m}^{2m}k\binom{k-1}{m-1}=m\sum_{k=m}^{2m}\binom{k}{m}
=m\binom{2m+1}{m+1}=m\binom{2m+1}{m}.$$
where we applied [Hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).

The case $n=2m-1$ can be treated in a similar way:
$$\sum_{k=m}^{2m-1}k\binom{k-1}{m-1}=m\sum_{k=m}^{2m-1}\binom{k}{m}
=m\binom{2m}{m+1}=m\binom{2m}{m-1}.$$